# Unity - Call Keyboard Input from a script?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'll try to explain this the best I can. Let's say I have 2 if statements that both send a Debug.Log message to console, like this:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("c")){
    Debug.Log("C was pressed!");
}

if(Input.GetKeyDown("b")){
    Debug.Log("b was pressed!");
}
```

We of course know that we'll get these messages when we press the appropriate keys. But what if I want to get another script to trigger these if statements instead of the keyboard doing it?

If I have a list of if statements that are taking in a keyboard input like these ones, is there a way to trigger these if statements **through code** or would I have to change the condition?

Comment: You want to call Debug.Log("C was pressed!"); though code?

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I don't think that simulating keyboard input is the way to go here. What I suppose would be better, is putting the statements inside new methods, which can be called from other scripts.

```
public void HandleInputC ()
{
    Debug.Log("C was pressed (or simulated).");
}
public void HandleInputD ()
{
    Debug.Log("D was pressed (or simulated).");
}

private void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
        HandleInputC();
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        HandleInputD();
}
```

This also makes it easier and more readable to make extensions to the individual methods, while keeping an overview on their purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. Yes, its definitely possible. Let's say you want to make a ghost of your player which you will replay later. So save all keystrokes the player makes in a list and then return keystrokes from this list. The idea is to make a custom **KeyStrokeRecorder** class which has a method called ***GetKey***. Then instead of calling ***Input.GetKeyDown*** call ***KeyStrokeRecorder.instance.GetKey***. See the code below.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class KeyStrokeRecorder : MonoBehaviour {

    public class KeyStroke {
        public enum KeyState {
            Idle,
            Pressed,
            Released,
        }
        public KeyCode keycode; 
        public string time;
        public KeyState state;          
    }       

    public List<KeyStroke> mKeyStrokes;
    public RecorderState recorderState = RecorderState.Idle;
    public static KeyStrokeRecorder instance;

    void Awake(){
        instance = this;    
    }

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {
         if( isRecording || isPlayback)
             gameTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    float gameTime = 0;    
    bool isRecording = false;       
    bool isPlayback = false;
    public bool GetKey(KeyCode keycode)
    { 
        if( isPlayback )
        {
            for(int i=0; i<mKeyStrokes.Count; i++)
            {
                float tTime;
                float.TryParse(mKeyStrokes[i].time, out tTime);

                if( mKeyStrokes[i].keyname == keycode.ToString() )
                {
                    if( gameTime > tTime-0.5f && gameTime < tTime+0.5f )
                    {
                        if( mKeyStrokes[i].state == KeyStroke.State.Pressed)
                            return true;
                        else
                            return false;
                    } 
                } 
            }    
            return false;
        }
        else if( isRecording )
        {
            KeyStroke keystroke = new KeyStroke();
            keystroke.keyname = keycode.ToString();
            keystroke.time = gameTime.ToString();

            if( Input.GetKeyDown(keycode) )
            {                   
                keystroke.state = KeyStroke.State.Pressed;    
                mKeyStrokes.Add(keystroke);                 
            }
            else if( Input.GetKeyUp(keycode) )
            {                   
                keystroke.state = KeyStroke.State.Released;     
                mKeyStrokes.Add(keystroke);
            }
        }    
        return Input.GetKey(keycode);
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you some idea.